# Cannot create Scheduled task with powershell that has option "run only when user is logged on"

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Does anyone know how to create a script that will enable me to set the option run only when user is logged on? I have searched for hours but found no good solution. The problem is that this program cannot run in the background and must therefor, from my knowledge run only when user is logged on. Any advice is apreciated

```
$taskName = 'task name'
$taskDescription = 'task desc'
$executable = "program.exe"
$workingDir = "C:\utv"
$user = "user"
$password = "password"

Write-Host "Configuring scheduled task"
Write-Host " - Executable: $workingDir\$executable"
Write-Host " - User: $user"
Write-Host "pw: $password"

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$workingDir\$executable"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 00:01 
$existingTask = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like     $taskName}
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $user
if ($existingTask) {
    Write-Host "Existing task found, updating..."
    Set-ScheduledTask `
        -TaskName $taskName  `
        -Action $action `
        -Trigger $trigger -User $user -Password $password
}
else {
    Write-Host "Creating new task..."
    Register-ScheduledTask `
        -TaskName $taskName `
        -Description $taskDescription `
        -Action $action `
        -Trigger $trigger -User $user -Password $password
}
Write-Host "Setting Repetition properties"
$newTask = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName}

$newTask.Triggers.repetition.Duration = 'PT23H'
$newTask.Triggers.repetition.Interval = 'PT60M'
$newTask.Principal.LogonType = 
$newTask | Set-ScheduledTask -User $user -Password $password

Write-Host "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script seems to missing some parameters.

```
$newTask.Principal.LogonType =
```

Setting this value to S4U should select "Run whether user is logged in or not" but it may set "Do not store your password..." tick box below it. Calling Register-ScheduledTask with a -User or -Password parameters on it should default to the desired output so New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal is not needed or editing the task Principal.LogonType may not be necessary.

Also, when using -User and -Password parameters on Register-ScheduledTask  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\disabledomaincreds** must be set to 0 and secpol.msc and the user must be added to **secpol.msc > Local Security Policy > User Rights Assignment > Log on as service**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set "Run when user is Logged on" because that is the default setting.

Comment: On windows10 any task I create using Register-ScheduledTask gets created with "Run whether user is logged on or not"

Comment: @ArcSet  I have tried this, however it seems that when you spesify username and password that it is set it run wheather user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution and discovered it through the error I was receiving: `Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified name parameters`.

This basically means you have to look at the syntax paragraphs for [Set-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/set-scheduledtask?view=windowsserver2019-ps), and check which parameters are allowed.  If you are using `New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal`, and registering a principal with the scheduled task, then you'll notice that `-User` and `-Password` are not allowed with it:

```
Set-ScheduledTask
   [[-Principal] <CimInstance>]
   [[-Action] <CimInstance[]>]
   [[-TaskPath] <String>]
   [[-Settings] <CimInstance>]
   [[-Trigger] <CimInstance[]>]
   [-TaskName] <String>
   [-CimSession <CimSession[]>]
   [-ThrottleLimit <Int32>]
   [-AsJob]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Make sure to set `-LogonType` (such as Interactive) and `-RunLevel` for `New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal`.  I found this Windows Developer link for [Principal.LogonType property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/principal-logontype), which gives a better explanation on `-LogonType` than PowerShell's.